# Using `-to` instead of `-t` when using YouTube link as input

Tags: bash, ffmpeg, video, bash-scripting, youtube-dl

[This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388148/216754) shows how to get a portion of a YouTube video by using URLs as input. The command works mostly fine, but I want to avoid using `-t` as I need to cut between specific timestamps and I'd rather not have to calculate the difference between timestamps beforehand.

However, when I try to adapt the command to use `-to` instead:

```
# get URLs
youtube-dl --get-url --youtube-skip-dash-manifest "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfnzBYV5fxs"

# crop 1 min from 6 mins onwards
ffmpeg -ss 00:06:00.00 -i "$video_url" -ss 00:06:00.00 -i "$audio_url" -to 00:07:00.00 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast test.mkv
```

...it ignores the second timestamp and downloads until the end. Why is this, and can it be fixed?

Both `ffmpeg` and `youtube-dl` versions are relatively recent and I've used the `-to` option without issue before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `-to` on the inputs when using `-ss` for inputs.

`ffmpeg -ss 00:06:00.00 -to 00:07:00.00 -i "$video_url" -ss 00:06:00.00 -to 00:07:00.00 -i "$audio_url" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast test.mkv`

Comment: As usual, lightning-fast answer and works perfectly - thank you. Can I confirm with you whether the two sets of timestamps are needed here? It feels idiomatic of an old version of FFmpeg but I can't be sure

Comment: Each `ss/to` pair applies to the `-i` immediately after it, so yes.